# Microsoft Access Cant Remove duplicates that contains Null value

Tags: ms-access, null, duplicates

I am having trouble removing/finding duplicates when a value in a certain column contains a null value

This was my original Criteria

```
    In (SELECT [PQT] FROM [Departure] As Tmp GROUP BY [PQT],[IDNUSER],[Name]
    HAVING Count(*)>1  And [IDNUSER] = [Departure].[IDNUSER] And [Name] = [Departure].[Name])
```

For example, lets say Name would be the column that could contain null values,

I tried replacing it with

```
And IIf(IsNull([Name]), " ", [Name]) = IIf(IsNull([Departure].[Name]), " ",
[Departure].[Name])
```

It didn't seem to work.
I also tried using NZ, with no success

Here are example datas that my table would contain

```
**PQT**     **IDNUSER**      **Name**  
BNC          001              Bob  
BNC          001              Bob
BNC          002              
BNC          002
```

Results of my current query
The 2 first data with the IDNUSER 001 is considered as a duplicate since all fields have values.
but IDNUSER 002 would not be considered as a duplicate since the value in Name is null.
I would like my query to find all duplicates.

Comment: That IIf statement doesn't make sense, can you simplify your question (and definately the SQL) please? Also, even if this SQL worked I would be surprised if it ran in less than 10 years, I think we need to have a look at streamlining this SQL from the beginning : )

Comment: Sorry about that, I modified my question and tried to make things clearer. I hope this is better. Thanks

Comment: Just a word of advice, you mention working with Nulls however Access treats "Nulls" and "Blanks" as different things (weird I know) so the best way to guarantee capture is to use IIf([Name] & "" = "", TrueValue, FalseValue)

Comment: That is exactly my problem, I tried doing IIf([Name] & "" = "", [Name], "fail") = IIf([Departure].[Name] & "" = "", [Departure].[Name], "fail") but it doesnt seem to find the duplicates that has a "null" or "blank" for name

Comment: Never mind, It worked. Thank you!! Both your IIf and Hans NZ worked,I could have sworn that It was not working when I tried in the pass. thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your sample data for Departure table, this is the output from the following SELECT query.

```
PQT IDNUSER user_name num_matches
BNC 001     Bob                 2
BNC 002                         2

SELECT
    d.PQT,
    d.IDNUSER,
    Nz([Name]," ") AS user_name,
    Count(*) AS num_matches
FROM Departure AS d
GROUP BY
    d.PQT,
    d.IDNUSER,
    Nz([Name]," ");
```

However your question mentioned removing duplicates, so I don't know what more to do at this point.  I don't see how you can distinguish between the 2 Bob rows ... which one to discard and which one to keep.  That would be possible if we had a unique column (such as a primary key) to distinguish between them.  Alternatively you could store the output from this GROUP BY query into another table with what the Access UI calls an "append query".  The pattern for such a query would be similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO OtherTable (
    PQT,
    IDNUSER,
    user_name,
    num_matches
    )
SELECT
    d.PQT,
    d.IDNUSER,
    Nz([Name]," ") AS user_name,
    Count(*) AS num_matches
FROM Departure AS d
GROUP BY
    d.PQT,
    d.IDNUSER,
    Nz([Name]," ");
```

Notice also I consolidated the two rows with IDNUSER = 002 into one row.  That was my best guess as to what you wanted.  However my inclination would be to require values in the Name column --- in other words prohibit Nulls.  But if you need to allow the Nulls and want them handled differently, tell us what you want.

**Edit**: Looking at this again, I don't see a real need for the NZ() function.  This version counts the matches correctly even when the groups include Null for [Name].

```
SELECT
    d.PQT,
    d.IDNUSER,
    [Name] AS user_name,
    Count(*) AS num_matches
FROM Departure AS d
GROUP BY
    d.PQT,
    d.IDNUSER,
    [Name];
```